# Finding the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I would like to find the exact value of $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}dx.$$

First of all we know that it exists and must be $\hspace{0.1cm}$$\leq1$$\hspace{0.1cm}$ because$\hspace{0.1cm}$ $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\leq1$.

But how would we go about finding the exact value?

Thanks.

Comment: @legâteauaufromage The limits are different though. Wolfram also says that the integral is not equal to $\pi$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sinx%5E2%2Fx%5E2+from+0+to+1

Comment: @legâteauaufromage Duplicate how? The upper limit is $1$, not infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate by parts $$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x&= \lim_{x\to a}\left[\frac{-\sin^2 x}{x}\right]_{x=a}^1 +\int_0^1\frac{\sin(2x)}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x\\ & \overset{t=2x}{=} -\sin^2(1) + \int_0^2 \frac{\sin t}{t}\ \mathrm{d}t\\ &= \text{Si}(2)-\sin^2(1)\approx 0.89734\end{aligned}$$
Where $\text{Si}$ is the [sine integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). I doubt the existence of a nice closed form.

Comment: Use limit at $x=0$ for the first line.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey done.

Comment: It would be better if you write $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to0}\left[-\frac{\sin^2x}{x}\right]_{x=a}^1$.

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary because it is too obvious.

Comment: *obvious* has no explanatory value

Comment: Okay, I've edited it.